# Color output of linux command similar to 'watch -d' to highlight differences?

Tags: diff, watch

I'm at the beginning of shell scripting etc. and a bit challenged to find the proper way of colorzing a command's repeating output, similar to the -d option in the watch command.

I want to see the changes of lsof and some other commands. That means, I want only the changed/new lines to be in red (instead of highlighted with a white background and highlighting all the following lines). Is there an elegant way to get it done with diff or any other command?

Example: A red line shows a new connection via SSH.

[image]

(I know, I could GREP for ESTABLISHED here, but not every command I want to watch gives me a keyword to search for. So I have to look for new/changed line in the output.)

Comment: That's what watch is for. But I suppose you could lsof > /tmp/thing && lsof > /tmp/thing2 && diff /tmp/thing /tmp/thing2

Comment: Have a look at [`multitail`](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=multitail) as well, which is a full-screen log viewer. You can monitor the output of processes or pipelines as well as disk files, and set up filtering and highlighting rules based on lines that match a pattern. It doesn't have anything like `watch -d` to my knowledge, but worth adding to the toolbox regardless. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a way to achieve it. I wanted to avoid file operations (tmpfs and such) for performance and latency reasons. The trick is to tell `dwdiff` or `wdiff` in its two arguments what the output of a command **is** and **was** within the same iteration. Process substitution was my helping hand:

```
while true; do p1=$p2; p2=$(clear; iotop -ob -n1); 
    dwdiff -y "\010" -1 -c <(echo "$p1") <(echo "$p2"); sleep 1; done
```

The `-y "\010"` removes the space before the changed word to keep the columns nicely aligned. `$p1` and `$p2` are used to keep the scope for the process substitutions `<(...)`. Providing the output in the substitutions directly didn't work for me. I got this hint from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261928/scope-of-variables-in-a-process-substitution) post.

Maybe there's a much simpler solution and I just got too complicated after all. Feel free to post it!

Comment: wondering how to make the highlighted colors stay, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ANSI` escape sequences. To set a color and style desired, there is a syntax `\033[#m` where # can be a valid set of semicolon separated numbers.

You can define colors such as

```
CLEAR="\033[0m"
GREEN="\033[0;32m"
BLUE="\033[0;34m"
PURPLE="\033[0;35m"
RED="\033[0;31m"
YELLOW="\033[1;33m"
```

And use them such as `echo -e "${GREEN}Updated${CLEAR}"`

[Check here for more reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors)

Comment: Thanks. I already tried this. To clarify my needs I just updated my post with a screenshot.