# Scope of variables in a process substitution

Tags: bash, variable, process-substitution

I have a command which takes two arguments. Assume we want to create both arguments by process substitution:

```
cat <(var=123; echo $var) <(echo $var)
```

What has to be done, to make $var available in the second substitution?

Comment: The problem is that you are only assigning `var` in your first subshell; `var` is thus only available within its scope.  You might want something like `var=123; cat <(echo $var) <(echo $var)`

Comment: Okay, this makes it readable, but not writable. I need to alter $var.

Comment: `var=123; PARAM1=$(var=456 echo $var); PARAM2=$var; cat <(echo $PARAM1) <(echo $PARAM2)` is about as close as I cam come to what it looks like you're asking for.

Comment: What has to be done? A shell rewrite that'll use threads instead of forks. That's probably not going to happen anytime soon.

Comment: DopeGhoti's second comment did the trick. Thanks a lot for that, @DopeGhoti! My initial goal is to color the differences of a command output over time. For example from `iotop`. I cannot do it via writing its output to tmpfs, due to timing issues. It gets me too many false positives.

Comment: Here's my initial question: [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260241/color-output-of-linux-command-similar-to-watch-d-to-highlight-differences/261941#261941)

Comment: My comments have been worked into an answer.  Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are only assigning `var` in the first subshell; the second subshell doesn't have access to anything assigned therein.  To access a variable in both, you need to declare it beforehand:

```
var=123
cat <(echo $var) <(echo $var)
```

If you need to keep the original and track things that change it:

```
var=123                               # set the default value
PARAM1=$(/bin/something; echo $var)   # something could edit var's value
PARAM2=$(/bin/otherthing; echo $var)  # so could otherthing
cat <(echo $PARAM1) <(echo $PARAM2)
```